# Grep file in another file in bash script and compare the result

Tags: grep, compare

Is something wrong with:

`if grep -xf test $option #find exact pattern from test in $option file
    then
      if [ -s test ]; #if not empty
      then
         echo OK!
      fi
      else #if empty or not matched
         echo FAIL!
      fi`

I noticed that in some wrong cases, probably when `test` contains string, fails. Maybe quotes that I shall mind (-exf didn't work)?

Comment: What about a simple `grep` with `-f` flag, `grep -f file1 file2`? which searches the contents of `file1` on `file2`

Comment: No difference, tried also. Maybe quotes stuff, idk.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, please? (Just in English)

Comment: Code is edited.